# Do I need to release id's in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Example:

```
MyClass *funkStation = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[funkStation dance];
id tmp = funkStation;
...
[funckStation release];
```

I know that after I'm done with the funkStation object I need to release it, but what about the id tmp? 
Am thinking that it's not a copy of the original object, but just a pointer to the memory space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmp and funkstation refer to the same object. You only need to release this object once. Sending release to funkstation and tmp do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. You only release `funkStation`, but not `tmp`.

`tmp` should only be released if you gave it a retained pointer or a copy of the original object:

```
id tmp = [funkStation retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate an object explicitly, with alloc, you need to release it.
Same with copy.

ID is a pointer, so when you assign it, it only assign the pointer value, so you don't need to release both variables, as they will both reference the same object. If you do so, you'll certainly get a segfault.

Comment: Don't forget that you also have to release objects that you create using new.